# How run bottle application as docker-container?

Tags: python, docker, bottle

I make bottle-framework-application, it works fine on localhost. I use virtualenv.

Then i build docker container. My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY . .
RUN /bin/bash -c "source venv/bin/activate"
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "python3 index.py"
```

Biuld-process its OK:

```
(venv) kalinin@md ~/python/bottler $ docker build -t bottler .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  26.07MB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 7698f282e524
Step 2/4 : COPY . .
 ---> 9e182c969051
Step 3/4 : RUN /bin/bash -c "source venv/bin/activate"
 ---> Running in 2022e2fa7600
Removing intermediate container 2022e2fa7600
 ---> 16209d249539
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT python3 index.py
 ---> Running in 84594de70d72
Removing intermediate container 84594de70d72
 ---> d5057555ab1a
Successfully built d5057555ab1a
Successfully tagged bottler:latest
```

After build, i try run container:

```
docker run -i -t --rm -p 8000:8000 bottler
```

But get follow error message:

```
/bin/bash: python3: command not found
```

Please help my run application. After run i need see application in browser.

Comment: This is basically exactly what’s covered in the official Docker [Getting Started, Part 2: Containers](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial, which I consider a must-read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would suggest you use one of python images https://hub.docker.com/_/python as you are using ubuntu image which probably does not have python pre-installed.

Second I would suggest you define ENTRYPOINT as a single command/executable - in your case python

`ENTRYPOINT ["python"]`

And then add the path to the .py file in CMD definition

`CMD ["index.py"]`

The issue in your case is that in ubuntu image the python executable is not found in the $PATH since it is not pre-installed. Either you should install python on top of the ubuntu image or simply use a already existing python image from docker hub

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Dockerfile` to

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip install bottle
RUN /bin/bash -c "source venv/bin/activate"
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "python3 index.py"
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: thanks, but container not running: https://pastebin.com/BsazV0eQ
error at: from bottle import run, app . But packages is installed: https://pastebin.com/JyUrVL9J

Comment: that seems to be some bug in your code. Make sure that you have properly imported that module `import bottle`.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check it might be possible that `bottle` module is not installed in that container. Try that and let me know. If it works then please upvote and accept my answer. :)